# how to check that array inside an array has any value (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs

There is an array contentMetaDataList inside another array (content) which contents few field like title, name, etc. so how i can hide heading (smart tags: written inside p tag) when there is no title to display.

Smart Tags :

{{relatedcontent.title}}

Comment: can you show your code you described?

Comment: i guess question is little confusing, want i want is 
 i have an array of objects which contains field 'title' ,  if no title to show in the htlml view. then the p tag  should be hidden.  
  please check the link https://plnkr.co/edit/jVjpzJsZmbGYtgeIqVeY?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-show` in order to show/hide by condition,
and to check if all the objects in your array includes the title field, you can use `Array.every()`.

If you comment or remove one of those titles in the array, the wrapper `<div>` which show the titles won't be visible, but stays in the DOM tree. (removing from the DOM tree can be done by `ng-if`)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){
$scope.a = 'sdf';
  
  $scope.contentMetaDataList = [
    {
      title:"legislation_title",
      fieldValue:"refund of tax to certain persons",
      id:94346
    }, 
    
    {
      title:"Enterprise_title",
      fieldValue:"refund of tax to certain persons",
      id:94346
    },
    
    {
      title:"Related_title",
      fieldValue:"refund of tax to certain persons",
      id:94346
    }];
  
   $scope.checkTitle = function() {
      return $scope.contentMetaDataList.every(item => item.title);
   }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div>
          
          <div ng-show="checkTitle()">
            <p>Smart Tags : </p> 
            <div ng-repeat="relatedcontent in contentMetaDataList">
                  <div>
                      {{relatedcontent.title}}
                  </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

for more info:

[ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) 
[Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) 
[ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

Answer (score 0):

I would say add a `<span>` or some tag with a ngIf. `*ngIf="relatedcontent.title !== undefined"`

Comment: i guess question is little confusing, want i want is i have an array of objects which contains field 'title' , if no title to show in the htlml view. then the p tag should be hidden. please check the link https://plnkr.co/edit/jVjpzJsZmbGYtgeIqVeY?p=preview

Comment: Then I would add the ng-if to <p> and create a boolean variable. Then in the app.js loop through your array and if title === 'undefined' then activate then change the variable so <p> doesn't show